# Can you execute a q function from bash?

Tags: bash, kdb

I have a q script and a bash script which both could use a certain function to get the wait time in seconds.

so from the bash script I want to do something like :

```
export WAITINGTIME=$(q scriptName.q -function functionName)
```

and that WAITINGTIME should be set to 50 seconds for example which will be returned from the q script. is this possible? Sounds like it should be easy, but  I was wondering if anyone has experience with this.

Comment: You grep the output here. If the result echoes from the script will be `50`, then the variable will have `50`. If it's `blaat\n[debug] hello, world!\n50`, it will be that. Also, enclose the output as: `export WAITINGTIME="$(do_something)"`

Comment: @Bayou The quotes aren't necessary. The RHS of an assignment isn't subject to word-splitting or pathname expansion.

Comment: *is this possible?* ... have you tried this and if so does it work as expected?  if it does not work as expected then update the question with more details ... the (wrong) results and the (correct) expected results

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Don't know why I thought that. Perhaps only with reassigning variables such as `VAR2="${VAR1}"`

Comment: @QuestionMark : Why not? Of course it assumes that your q-program writes the `50` to stdout (and nothing else), but since you design this program, it is up to you to ensure this.

Comment: BTW, do you really need to `export` this? Environment space is a limited resource; it's better to use regular shell variables instead of environment variables when you can.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not demonstrate a failed attempt, and otherwise provides no reason to believe the OP's code doesn't work already out-of-the-box.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy OPs code likely doesn't work out of the box as by default a q/kdb instance will want to run in the foreground and stay up listening to STDIN so it doesn't automatically exit to return flow (and return a STDOUT) to the bash script. My answer below works as it runs the q script in the background

Comment: I really don't see how that's possible. `var=$(something &)` waits for `something` to close its stdout, just as `var=$(something)` waits for `something` to close its stdout _and exit_. Either way, `var` can't be assigned a value until `something`'s stdout is closed.

Comment: @terrylynch, ...wouldn't `</dev/null` be an easier way to stop the process from blocking on stdin, without needing to background it?

Comment: Yes that would also work - I've updated my answer with your suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a most basic example would be:

```
tlynch:~ $ cat scr.q
f1:{.z.P};
f2:{.z.N};
value(first .Q.opt[.z.x]`function;`)

tlynch:~ $ cat bash.sh
alias q=/opt/q3.5/l64/q
export WAITINGTIME=$(q scr.q -function $1 &)
echo "Result=$WAITINGTIME"
```

Then

```
tlynch:~ $ sh bash.sh f1
Result=2021.08.03D05:42:25.775601000
tlynch:~ $ sh bash.sh f2
Result=0D05:42:29.094209000
tlynch:~ $ sh bash.sh f1
Result=2021.08.03D05:42:31.880126000
```

EDIT: A cleaned-up version, taking into account various suggestions from Charles

```
tlynch:~ $ cat scr.sh
export QHOME=/opt/q3.5
WAITINGTIME=$(/opt/q3.5/l64/q scr.q -function $1 </dev/null)
echo "Result=$WAITINGTIME"

tlynch:~ $ sh scr.sh f1
Result=2021.08.03D14:14:22.188564000
tlynch:~ $ sh scr.sh f2
Result=0D14:14:24.381535000
```

Comment: Note that aliases aren't enabled by scripts by default -- if the above code works for you, I'm assuming either `q` is in your PATH so the alias is unneeded, or you've exported... whatever the environment variable to override default shell options is; I forget the name. `q() { /opt/q3.5/l64/q "$@"; }` would be more reliable. (As a different matter, `sh` is not bash -- even when the files are linked together, bash disables some features to be more compatible with POSIX sh when started under that name -- so naming a sh script "bash.sh" is a bit odd).

Comment: Yes, good points. A tidied-up version of my answer should still give the OP a direction to work towards

Comment: Aside: The POSIX standard specifies all-caps names to be used for environment variables, and variables that are meaningful to the shell; [variables with at least one lower-case name are reserved for application use](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html), meaning they won't be set by the shell or have inadvertent effects on the shell, so it's best practice to use variables in that namespace (which is to say, _not_ all-caps) when writing scripts and not explicitly intending to modify how the shell or other POSIX-standardized tools operate.

Comment: ...as a quick and easy example, `for PATH in /dir/*/` will break your shell by preventing it from locating utilities in `/bin` and friends, whereas `for path in /dir/*/` is fine.

Comment: BTW, also consider `-function "$1"` or `-function "$@"` as appropriate, instead of `-function $1`. The former passes through only the first parameter, keeping it as a single word if it contains spaces; the latter passes through _all_ positional parameters without performing string-splitting, glob expansion, or otherwise modifying them in any way. The original `-function $1` code gives you the worst of both worlds: It ignores all arguments other than the first one, and it string-splits and glob-expands that first argument, parsing it in a quite different way from how bash otherwise parses code.

Comment: ([BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) discusses some of the differences between how parameter expansion _actually_ works, and how folks who write `$1` unquoted expecting it to be usable for arguments with quotes/spaces/etc typically _expect_ it to work).